# D3: How to adjust SVG image path elements programmatically?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, svg-path

## Using Icons as Data Points

Inspired by the ability to use svg images as data elements, as [this block](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/950642) demonstrates, I wanted to take it a level further and use SVG images (SVG paths), so that I could also adjust their stroke color & thickness.

Here is a screenshot of the block I have linked above:

[image]

---

## Using SVG Paths as Icons

The code uses an image, instead of an SVG path.  I mimicked the code, pointing my equivalent of `.attr("xlink:href", "https://github.com/favicon.ico")` to an svg image instead.  E.g., `.attr("xlink:href", "../images/my_logo.svg")`, where `my_logo.svg` is an icon, similar to what is shown in the example above, but with a valid svg element.  E.g., the `my_logo.svg` element starts something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 20010904//EN"
 "http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-SVG-20010904/DTD/svg10.dtd">
<svg version="1.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
 width="900.000000pt" height="900.000000pt" viewBox="0 0 900.000000 900.000000"
 preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet">
<g transform="translate(0.000000,900.000000) scale(0.100000,-0.100000)">
<path d="M4280 8997 c-3 -2 -54 -7 -115 -10 -684 -37 -1449 -290 -2080 -690
-621 -393 -1182 -990 -1525 -1622 -24 -44 -53 -98 -65 -120 -44 -81 -139 -294
```

.
.
.

```
2310 880 278 21 516 20 785 -6z" stroke="red" stroke-width="2" fill="red" />
```

.
.
.

---

## Incorporating These SVG Path Files into D3 Environment

However, I am reading this SVG in incorrectly, so that it is treated as an image.  I am copying the example in the block mentioned above, which does things like:

```
node.append("image")
.attr("xlink:href", "https://github.com/favicon.ico")
```

Specifically, in my case I am trying to make a scatterplot, so my code looks like:

```
var points = svg.selectAll('image').data(data)
                .enter().append('image').classed('point', true)
                .attr("xlink:href", "../images/my_logo.svg")
```

This obviously brings the SVG in as an "image", which does not allow for me to adjust the stroke width or color or these things which I wish to adjust.  For instance, if I look at the elements in the console, using `d3.selectAll("image")`, I'll see that I have access to `x`, `y`, `width`, `height`, etc., just as I would with a normal **image**, not a truly flexible SVG path element.

### I know that the issue is because I am importing this icon **as an image**, but I just don't know the right way to do it.

Comment: Instead of `<image>` element, why don't you use the `<use>` one?

Comment: Hi @Kaiido I'm not sure how I would use `<use>`.  Would you be willing to provide an example?  However, I was able to successfully implement Ouroborus' example below (the answer I accepted).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You, of course, can't modify an SVG that's brought in as an image. You can, however, load the SVG via AJAX and manipulate and inject it from there. You may be better off using a format that is not strictly SVG so that it's easier to modify and inject. For example, an SVG fragment (just the contents of the `<svg>` element) would be directly injectable and then could be modified through CSS.

---

[Here is a full example](http://bl.ocks.org/ouroborus/553ef9a7edb5636366bacb2db68b8cee) to demonstrate how this can be done, using `d3.xhr`.

Comment: Hi Ouroborus, thanks!  Yes, I'm sure there is a better way.  I just don't know what that way is.  I don't normally work with SVG objects.  (I'm coming at D3 from a stats / data science background.)  Could you provide a toy example in your answer?  Thanks!

Comment: @MikeWilliamson I took the bl.ocks.org thing and [made some minor modifications to demonstrate](http://bl.ocks.org/ouroborus/553ef9a7edb5636366bacb2db68b8cee). It's not exactly optimal, in that d3.js expects you to build the SVG programmatically rather than loading it from an external resource.

Comment: thanks so much!!  That [demonstration you provided](http://bl.ocks.org/ouroborus/553ef9a7edb5636366bacb2db68b8cee) is **exactly** what I was looking for!